# The procedure entry point OCIStmlRelease could not be located PHP 5.6 OCI8 xammp

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oracle11g, oci8

I am using php 5.6(Xammp Apache Server) with oracle 11g installed.My php to oracle connectivity was working fine until yesterday i suddenly got this error when i start Apache service from the Xammp Control Panel.I got this error message.

> httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> the procedure entry point OCIStmlRelease could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library E:\xammp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll

Here are the configurations which i have done
I have uncommitted the line in php.ini

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

I have added following files in the php\ext folder

> php_oci8.dll and php_oci8_11g.dll

I have installed the Oracle Instant Client 11g and added it's path in Environment Variables to

```
C:\Oracle\instantclient_11_2;
```

but still i am getting the above error when i start my Apache server from xammp control panel and if i connect to oci8 using php then i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

i have been searching for almost 3 days on this issue but still could not find anything.It will be really helpful if someone can help me out on this.

Comment: php_oci8.dll needs Oracle 12 libraries.  You have Oracle 11 libraries.  Either use php_oci8_11g.dll or get Oracle Instant Client 12c.  I'd recommend the latter.  You can still connect back to Oracle 10.2 DB's, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by copying all the files from oracle instant 11g into the

> php.exe

Folder because when we start the xammp then first of all it looks for the OCI libraries in the php.exe folder.

which is located in the xammp folder.